# 2 elementary number theory problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So going back to my old number theory book by I. Niven, An introduction to the theory on numbers, I saw these problems:

**Question 1:** Find the triplets of number $(x,y,z)$ such that $x+y+z=119,$ and none exceed $59?$

**Question 2:** Find four integers $(x,y,z,w)$, such that they have the property $x\ge 0 , y\ge 1, z\ge 2, w\ge 3$, and satisfies $x+y+z+w = 15.$

I would appreciate the indepth explanation to solving these problems

Comment: Are these just finding one 3- or 4-tuple for each problem, all of them,  or what? Finding any one solution seems easy enough: just choose 2 (for Q1) or 3 (for Q2) numbers that meet the necessary properties, find the remaining number, and, if it doesn't exist, tweak as necessary. Just glorified trial-and-error.

Comment: Also shouldn't Q2 be stated as $x+y+z+w=15$? (instead of $=w=15$)

Comment: It says find for 1. 3- tuple and for 2. 4- tuple. I will make the edit Thank you.

Comment: Actually it only says triplets and quadruplets not tuples unless they imply the same thing?

Comment: "Triplet" and "3-tuple" basically mean the same thing; same for "quadruplet" and "4-tuple." Basically what I was asking, then, is "are you only tasked to find one such triplet/quadruplet". If so, the trial-and-error method I suggested is just as valid as any other. I could see something more "refined" being justified if it was finding all of the triplets/quadruplets, and I find it weird that you'd only be asked for one triplet/quadruplet in a textbook on number theory (but that might be a personal issue).

Comment: @AuroraBorealis do you want the number of such $x,y,z,w$?

Comment: I would like to know how many such triplets and quadruplets exist? Could you show me how to approach this question?

Comment: The name of the department of mathematics that this problem belongs to is _compositions_ of an integer. _Partitions_ is about the same thing _but_ without ordering of the parts. Both are thoroughly fascinating subjects and spawn some truly _mind-expanding_ theorems! Just put a google search in: "compositions of integer PDF", & you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I _think_ I've got it right this time! This is a _gorgeous_ theorem! ¶ Using $[x^n]$ to mean _the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of_, the number of compositions of n into k parts restricted to some set S is $$[x^n]\bigg(\sum_{s\in S}x^s\bigg)^k$$ ... so in _your_ example it's $$[x^{119}]\bigg(\sum_{s=60}^{119}x^s\bigg)^3 .$$ Actually that's for _all_ of them exceeding 59! _This_ is the answer to yours - $$[x^{119}]\bigg(\sum_{s=1}^{59}x^s\bigg)^3 .$$ I put this _whole comment_ in the wrong place at first anyway! The computation looks _formidable_, though ... you need better really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are linear equations for which there is an established algorithm to solve, in terms of paramatrisations. I'll do the first question; see if you can generalise the idea to the second.
Recall that solving a linear equation in two variables over $\mathbb Z$ is done like this: if $ax+by=c$, then find a particular solution $(x_0,y_0)$. Then all the solutions are given by $x=x_0-bt$, $y=y_o+at$, where $t$ ranges over all integral values. (Can you prove this?) Now let's move on to the three-variable case.

Set $u+v=k$. We have the simultaneous equations
$$\begin{cases}u+v=k,\\k+w=119.\end{cases}$$
If we treat $k$ like a constant in the first equation we obtain the paramatrisation $u=k-t_1$, $v=t_1$. Treating $k$ like a variable in the second, we have $k=119-t_2$, $w=t_2$. Now, $u=k-t_1=119-t_1-t_2$. Hence, all the possible integer solutions are given by $(u,v,w)=(119-t_1-t_2,t_1,t_2)$. But none of the three variables exceed $59$, so we have the bounds $119-t_1-t_2\leq59$, $t_1\leq 59$, $t_2\leq 59$. In other words, $t_1,t_2$ are any two integers so that each is not exceeding $59$ and their sum is at least $60$. This provides a complete paramatrisation and hence solution to the problem.

Comment: You talking about the _simplex_ algorithm?

Comment: Can we solve 2) in a similar way?

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey I've never heard of that name, so maybe. I never thought this algorithm was complicated enough to deserve a name of its own.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Yes, you can.

Comment: @YiFan -- actually ... no it's not the simplex algorithm - that's about _optimising_ problems comprising inequalities of this kind by finding the point at which a hyperplane _touches_ a simplex. I was just browsing & responding a tad over-hastily. I'm not recommending _particularly_ that you go & study the algorithm if it's not in your way _anyway_ ... but if you were to do so you would see the connection.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey This shouldn't be a comment under my answer. If you *really* want, post it under the question, not here. It's off topic because the OP did not put any of their efforts in the question, so it lacks context.

Answer (score 1):

you can model such these equations like this:
first **Q2)**
suppose we have 15 identical balls and want to put them in 4 different baskets labeled as x, y, z, w such that basket y must has at least 1 ball inside it, basket z must has at least 2 balls inside it and basket w must has 3 balls inside it.
so we initially satisfy these criterias by just putting 1, 2 and 3 balls in baskets y, z and w respectively.
now we have 15-(1+2+3)=9 balls left with 3 basket which have no specific criterias: `x + y' + z' + w' = 9`
now if we put 3 delimiters between 9 balls to put them into 4 baskets equivalently: sections 1, 2, 3 and 4 corresponds to baskets x, y, z and w respectively.
one possible division is as follows:  "`{} | {OOO} | {} | {OOOOOO}`" ("O" represents a ball and "|" represents a delimiter). its corresponding answer is `(x, y', z', w') = (0, 3, 0, 6)` that satisfies the equation `x + y' + z' + w' = 9`. so `(x, y, z, w) = (0, 3+1, 0+2, 6+3)` is a valid answer for main equation `x + y + z + w = 15`.
so the problem is to find all the linear permutations of 9 identical balls and 3 identical delimiters. and finally here is the number of valid (x, y, z, w) answers :

> $\frac{(9+3)!}{9!3!} = \frac{{12}\times{11}\times{10}}{6} = 220$

**Q1)**
the problem is to find the number of (x, y, z) answers that satisfy the following equation:

> $D \sim [{x + y + z = 119; {0}\leq{x}\leq{59}, {0}\leq{y}\leq{59}, {0}\leq{z}\leq{59}}]$

now let:

> $I \sim [{x + y + z = 119; {0}\leq{x}, {0}\leq{y}, {0}\leq{z}}]$
>   $I_1 \sim [{x + y + z = 119; {60}\leq{x}, {0}\leq{y}, {0}\leq{z}}]$
>   $I_2 \sim [{x + y + z = 119; {0}\leq{x}, {60}\leq{y}, {0}\leq{z}}]$
>   $I_3 \sim [{x + y + z = 119; {0}\leq{x}, {0}\leq{y}, {60}\leq{z}}]$

by inclusion-exclusion-identity we have:

> $D = {\bar{I_1}}\cap{\bar{I_2}}\cap{\bar{I_3}} = \overline{({I_1}\cup{I_2}\cup{I_3})} = I - (I_1 + I_2 + I_3 - {I_1}
> \cap{I_2} - {I_1}\cap{I_3} - {I_2}\cap{I_3} + {I_1}\cap{I_2}\cap{I_3})$

also:

> ${I_1}\cap{I_2} \sim [{x + y + z = 119; {60}\leq{x}, {60}\leq{y}, {0}\leq{z}}] \rightarrow unsatisfiable$
>   ${I_1}\cap{I_3} \sim [{x + y + z = 119; {60}\leq{x}, {0}\leq{y}, {60}\leq{z}}] \rightarrow unsatisfiable$
>   ${I_2}\cap{I_3} \sim [{x + y + z = 119; {0}\leq{x}, {60}\leq{y}, {60}\leq{z}}] \rightarrow unsatisfiable$
>   ${I_1}\cap{I_2}\cap{I_3} \sim [{x + y + z = 119; {60}\leq{x}, {60}\leq{y}, {60}\leq{z}}] \rightarrow unsatisfiable$

so the answer is:

> $D = \frac{(119+2)!}{119!2!} - {3}\times{\frac{(119-60+2)!}{(119-60)!2!}} + {3}\times{0} - 0 = \frac{{121}\times{120}}{2} - {3}\times{\frac{{61}\times{60}}{2}} = 1770$